# How to change precision of dates in x-axis Plots julia?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Suppose I have the following data and its plot:

```
using DataFrames
using StatsPlots
using Plots
using Dates

dates = Date(2021, 1, 1):Day(1):Date(2023, 3, 28)
n = length(dates)

df = DataFrame(
  date=dates,
  col1=rand(n),
  col2=rand(n)
)

@df df plot(
  :date, cols(2:3),
  legend=:outerright,
  xlabel="Date",
  ylabel="Val",
  title="Test plot",
  size=(1000, 600),
  dpi=300,
  left_margin=5Plots.mm,
  bottom_margin=5Plots.mm,
)
```

[image]

How can I change the precision of dates to monthly or quarterly in x-ticks?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `xticks` but you need to create a subset of DateTimes that you want to display in your x-axis, for example:

```
julia> tm_ticks = round.(dates, Month(1)) |> unique;
julia> plot(dates, rand(n), xticks=(tm_ticks, Dates.format.(tm_ticks, "uu/yyyy")), xrot=45, xminorticks=true, xlim=extrema(dates))
```

which will create something like:
[image]

You can adjust `tm_ticks`, for instance, with `Month(3)` to create x-axis for quarterly ticks. ;)